# Is there a way to stop all the extra text in an exception message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a Grid view with two columns that have drop down lists. This drop down lists save as soon as a value is selected. I want to prevent the user from selecting a value in the second drop down list without selecting a value from the first one. So the first drop down list shouldn't be blank.

```
public static void UpdateMemReasonSecond(int SerNoID, string sel)
{
    JobOutturn SerNo = new JobOutturn(SerNoID);
    SerNo.MemReasonSecond = sel;
    SerNo.MemDate = DateTime.Now;
    SerNo.MemUser = CurrentUser.Username;
    SerNo.Update();

    if (SerNo.MemReason == "" & SerNo.MemReasonSecond != "")
    {
        throw new Exception("Please fill in first reason");
    }
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
function UpdateMemReasonSecond(SerNoID, sel) {
        PageMethods.UpdateSecondMemReasonUserControl(SerNoID, sel, OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFailReason);
    }
```

So the exception works but the error message that comes up contains a lot of extra lines and not just my message. Is there a way to only display my message?

[image]

Comment: `ex.Message`, you mean?

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for this at all

Comment: "Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

Comment: Don't do it it is a bad practice, instead look into Cascading Drop Down Lists e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915527/cascading-dropdownlist-and-listbox-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer its a static method so I cannot just create an alert message. Only exception message seem to display.

Comment: @PaulZahra I don't need cascading drop down lists, I just want to check if the first drop down is blank and the second one isn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you mean a try and catch?

Comment: @user123456789 Just put a message in the session, then in your front end check if the session message is there and then alert the user.

Answer (score 0):

To use `ClientScript` inside a static method pass the Page object as a parameter to your static method.[Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) is not [static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).You can not call non static fields inside static method.So you need to pass the page object to your static method as a parameter.

```
public static void UpdateMemReasonSecond(int SerNoID, string sel ,Page page)
{
   JobOutturn SerNo = new JobOutturn(SerNoID);
        SerNo.MemReasonSecond = sel;
        SerNo.MemDate = DateTime.Now;
        SerNo.MemUser = CurrentUser.Username;
        SerNo.Update();

        if (SerNo.MemReason == "" & SerNo.MemReasonSecond != "")
        {

            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(),"alert", "<script>alert('Please fill in first reason');</script>");
        }
    }
```